# I can't figure out why my VLOOKUP function isn't working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to use a VLOOKUP formula in one of my Google Spreadsheets. It seems to be working, but only sporadically. A good half of the column with the VLOOKS are coming in blank. I keep looking over them, trying to rewrite them, but it isn't changing anything. Here is a link to a sample sheet: [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dSjP1dUUO5AvDAYGbvk4VNEPHZE9Sq2dhnpGyblroIM/edit?usp=sharing)

This is one of the last iterations of the VLOOKUP, in column C, on "Sheet2":

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A8,B8),{ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(OGTransact!A$2:A,OGTransact!B$2:B)),OGTransact!C$2:C},2)
```

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry I haven't time to write a full answer, but basically you need to use exact match =VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A8,B8),{ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(OGTransact!A$2:A,OGTransact!B$2:B)),OGTransact!C$2:C},2,false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what @Tom Sharpe said, If you want to find the exact match of your data, You have to put `FALSE` for the `is_sorted` paramater.

So the modified formula is :

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A2,B2),{ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(OGTransact!A$2:A,OGTransact!B$2:B)),OGTransact!C$2:C},2,FALSE)
```

Another **Alternative Solution** is using `XLOOKUP Function`:

```
=XLOOKUP(CONCAT(E3,F3),ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(A$2:A,B$2:B)),C$2:C,"NONE",0)
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

***Note: You can change the range to suit your needs.***

*Reference:*

1. [VLOOKUP Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
2. [XLOOKUP Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=FILTER(OGTransact!C:C,OGTransact!A:A=A2,OGTransact!B:B=B2)
```

For dynamic spill result, usr `MAP()` with `FILTER()`. Try-

```
=MAP(A2:A15,B2:B15,LAMBDA(x,y,FILTER(OGTransact!C:C,OGTransact!A:A=x,OGTransact!B:B=y)))
```

If you have chance to return multiple dates by filter function then you can use `CHOOSEROWS()` function to have only 1 row as result.

```
=MAP(A2:A15,B2:B15,LAMBDA(x,y,CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(OGTransact!C:C,OGTransact!A:A=x,OGTransact!B:B=y),1)))
```

[image]